Displaying interactive HTML knitted R-Markdown file within existing Jekyll site hosted on GitHub Pages
I have a personal website hosted on GitHub Pages using this Jekyll template, where I'd like to embed an R Markdown project I recently completed in RStudio within a post for the "Projects" tab explaining the background for the project. You can look through my repo here.
I first tried to use {%include filename.html %} within the .md for the post, which I hoped would display the R plots and output (like regression tables). It failed to build and deploy to pages, the reasons for which I believe is explained in this post. I tried stripping the extraneous tags as suggested in the most upvoted answer and it failed to deploy again, still due to Liquid, with this error:
Rendering Liquid: _projects/longerProjectTitle.md github-pages 231 | Error: Liquid syntax error (/github/workspace/_includes/CrashingWalkingWeb.html line 2076): Variable '{{if(e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t={}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/ included
 

I also tried the solution in the second answer on that post and the tutorial on this website, both of which deployed but came up with exactly the same problem, which is that the formatting is nowhere near what I wanted. It interprets the R as math for some reason and activates none of the Markdown formatting.
Ideally, I'd like to have something like what shows up when I open the HTML file knitted from R-Markdown in my browser, only within that particular page on my website, complete with the tooltips when I hover over my plotly plots and the echoed printouts from running the code chunks.

In retrospect, I misunderstood some of the instructions for YAML heading within RStudio as headers in the file uploaded to GitHub. I was able to generate a GitHub Flavored Markdown file by knitting with "output: github_document." Putting this file in my site's repository worked to fix formatting. I still have not found out a good way to embed the plotly plots and decided to link to them externally instead.
